# Abandoned carts being all updated at same time

Tags: magento2.2.4, abandoned-cart

Periodically the abandoned carts are all being updated at same time. It happened 3-4 times by now. I don't know what is causing the behaviour and if it is an actual problem.

Below is an image from the most recent ocurrence.

[image: Abandoned carts]

I searched if it was a cron job, server update, database error, but it seems to be a Magento behaviour. My Magento version is 2.2.4.

I'm a bit lost. Please ask for any details and I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out it is not a bug. Every time I update some info from the product that is on a cart, the abandoned carts table update itself, it is a normal behaviour.